# How to send the unchanged value to the server in gwt RequestFactory?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gxt

Iam very new to the GWT.

i have an issue like

two text fields like code and reference.

first i fill the code (i dont fill the reference)and i save the declaration and i send the declaration

after getting some response

again i edit the form with referense no and i again i send the declaration.

here the problem is the both values i need at server side to generate EDi. but iam getting only reference(recently changed).
as per my knowledge RequestFactory only sends the recent changes. but i need both i.e which is not changed and which is changed. so how to get?

please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request Factory is meant for saving the changes only i.e., delta. Your case is more of a use case for [GWT RPC](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html). Try RPC instead of request factory for this case